# TypeORM QueryBuilder from clause with alias

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm having trouble creating a materialized view in Postgres using the query builder. I'm selecting from multiple tables, joining the results, and then selecting from the final result. I've included a simplified version that shows the trouble I'm having.

The second parameter of the from method sets the alias for the select clause. The resulting SQL (shown below) has `from (...) "Logins"`. Using double quotes around Logins is causing an error. Without them, the query runs, but with them it fails with `SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "logins"`

Can anyone help me with this?

**View Entity:**

```js
@ViewEntity({
  expression: connection => {
    const loginQb = connection
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .from(LoginEvent, "LE")
      .select("COUNT(LE.id)", "num_logins");
    return connection
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select('Logins."num_logins"')
      .from(`(${loginQb.getQuery()})`, "Logins");
  }
})
class MyView {
  ...
}
```

**Resulting SQL:**

```sql
SELECT Logins."num_logins" FROM (SELECT COUNT("LE"."id") AS "num_logins" FROM "LoginEvent" "LE") "Logins"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have the answer already. It seems you are missing alias in "num_logins"
Cna you try it and see if this fixes the issue. Please look at the "num_logins". I havent tried it yet but it looks like that might be the issue

```
@ViewEntity({
  expression: connection => {
    const loginQb = connection
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .from(LoginEvent, "LE")
      .select("COUNT(LE.id)", "LE"."num_logins");
    return connection
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select('Logins."num_logins"')
      .from(`(${loginQb.getQuery()})`, "Logins");
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, Joey! I stopped working on this project, and I think I ended up writing plain SQL, but if I have time, I'll loop back around and see what happened.

Comment: Oh sure. No problem